# Xcode 15 doesn't support for iOS distribution certificate any more?

Tags: provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate, xcode15, ios-app-signing

The problem is the apple distribution certificate expired last year, and out team created a new iOS distribution cert, and a new provisioning profile out of this. But in Xcode, it seems cannot detect the new cert and get this error "Signing certificate is invalid." Is it because Xcode 15 no linger support iOS distribution/development cert?

[the ios cert is loaded  here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypyqt.png)
[but it still uses the previous expired cert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiM4v.png)